# Date formatting on x-axis highchart

Tags: json, charts, highcharts

I am a beginner in highcharts. I was trying something and got stuck. I tried to plot a line graph using json data . The graph is plotting correctly but in x-axis date is not showing correctly always it showing jan 1 1971. I want the exact date that given in the json data.

```
    "linechart":[{
                "name":"Average Conversation Length (In minutes)",
                "data":[["2020,02,12",12],["2020,02,13",13],["2020,02,14",5],["2020,02,15",6],["2020 02,16",8],["2020,02,17",23],["2020,02,18",11]]},
             {
                 "name":"Average Number of Conversations",
                 "data":[["2020,02,12",10],["2020,02,13",21],["2020,02,14",19],["2020,02,15",2],["2020,02,16",3],["2020,02,17",38],["2020,02,18",8]]
             }]
```

I tried these much options in x-axis but no result

```
        xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Average session length (in minutes)'
        },
        tickAmount: 5,
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          day: '%m/%d/%Y',
          week: '%m/%d/%Y',
          month: '%m/%d/%Y',
        },
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontFamily: "Open Sans"
          },
        }
    },
    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },
```

Comment: Have you considered to use the xAxis `category` type rather than the `datetime`? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tjyw2cr1/ This solution doesn't require to parse your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
 var data = chartdata.linechart;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    obj.data.forEach(d => {
        d[0] = Date.parse(d[0]);
    });
}

console.log(data);
Highcharts.chart('linechart', {
    title: {
        text: 'Average session length by day'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Day'
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Average session length (in minutes)'
        },
        type: 'datetime',
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            }            
        }
    },

    series: data,
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
Highcharts.setOptions({lang: {noData: "No Data Available"}});
```